# When I switch working svn between mac and win, android-support-v7 lib's path in my project is changed every time?

Tags: android, macos, android-support-library

I create a project and include android-support-v7 appcompt lib. I have included this lib into my project's private libs(project properties->android->library), but I found an interesting thing: when I switch working environment between mac and win, the path of v7 lib is changed, so I must do as this every time: update my project from subversion, change v7 lib's path, recompile. Wwhat's a terrible thing!

Comment: I think it is posible with android studio

Comment: I think I have found the answer of this stupid question. I just need copy project code to my workspace, every thing is ok, because the path of lib is relative to working path, the path of sdk(v7 support lib code's path) is not same between windows and mac os x.

Comment: the configuration of lib path in file  project.properties, like this: "android.library.reference.1=../android-support-v7-appcompat", before I reimport project using copy mode to my workspace, this configuration is different in mac and windows.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to remove library from version.or else you can prefer using same ADT and version support in both platform . ie if you have updated ADT in window pls update the same revision of ADT and support library in Mac.

Comment: The problem is about library path is not same, not others.such as in mac the path is :/usr/xxx/document/adt/sdk/..., but in win, the path is : c:\develop\adt\sdk...